# How to return script from server for jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

We have a jQuery mobile site (ASP.NET MVC but that does not really matter for this question). jQuery mobile attaches to links and forms and automatically converts everything into AJAX requests.

Using classic jQuery `.ajax()` calls, it is possible to return plain Javascript like `alert('Data has been saved.');` from the server using `application/x-javascript` content type - jQuery performs automatic content type detection and handles the response correctly. This also works with AJAX form submissions - if the response is a script, it is executed, if the reponse is HTML, the form content can be replaced.

Unfortunately, jQuery mobile seems to always expect HTML in the server responses. If the server response is a script with `application/x-javascript` content-type, it just replaces the whole page with text `undefined`. If we disable AJAX for jQuery mobile and attach classic jQuery AJAX form, then it still shows errors although the script is executed after those errors are displayed to the user.

**Is it possible to return just plain Javascript code from the server as a response to jQuery mobile request?**